# Add counter for Matching ID based on value in another column in R

Tags: r, counter

I am struggling to think of what logic I will need to be able to come up with a counter/index for genuine matches and non genuine matches.
A simplified example of my data is as follows:

```
ID    track
x       10
x       10
x       3
x       3
x       1
y       2
```

The final data frame I wish to get is as follows:

```
ID     Track   Counter
x       10     1
x       10     1
x       3      2
x       3      2
x       1      3
y       2      1
```

Hence whenever the ID is the same and the track is the same put a counter in thr Counter column (starting with 1), whenever the ID is the same but then the Track changes make the counter +1, etc.
When a new ID comes up the counter starts from 1 again.

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Counter = cumsum(!duplicated(track)))
```

The trick is to use `duplicated` as to indicate unseen entries and `cumsum` to act as their counter. E.g.,

```
!duplicated(data$track[1:5])
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you

Comment: FYI this doesn't work if the track should ever switch to one that has already come up before.  For example, if the track switched to 3 again in ID x it would not register on the counter.

Comment: Ok, so basically make sure I order my data so I don't come across this issue?

Comment: It depends on the application.  Is there a situation where the track would revert to one that has already come up?  If so, does this need to increment the counter?

Answer (score 1):

@Julius' answer works if you have no repeating tracks.  If you run into a situation where the track may revert to a previous value, the counter will not be incremented.  If this is the case in your data and you need to increment the counter when that occurs, I would suggest using `lag` from dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(count = cumsum(track != lag(track, default = track[1]))+1)
```

Results with a couple more datapoints:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   ID [2]
#   ID    track count
#   <fct> <int> <dbl>
# 1 x        10     1
# 2 x        10     1
# 3 x         3     2
# 4 x         3     2
# 5 x         1     3
# 6 x         3     4
# 7 x         3     4
# 8 y         2     1
```

Comment: Thank you for the extension :)